# При подключении заголовка с cli vector код не компилируется

Tags: c++-cli

Мне нужно использовать vector из C++/CLI. Но как только я подключаю заголовочный файл вот таким образом:

```
#include <cliext/vector>
```

то код перестаёт компилироваться, хотя я даже не использую экземпляры этого вектора. Вываливаются следующие ошибки:

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\cliext\iterator(197): error C2059: syntax error: ':'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\cliext\iterator(265): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'cliext::ConstBidirectionalIterator<_Cont_t>' being compiled
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\cliext\iterator(197): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding ':'; skipping apparent function body
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\cliext\iterator(265): fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
```

Использую Visual Studio Community 2017 15.9.3

Comment: Тут играет роль ещё два момента, 1)какие #include написаны до данного. Если никаких - то нормально компилятор себя ведёт. Лучше инклюд дописывать вниз. 2) это у вас unmanaged scope или managed. Возможно этот переключатель даст результат.

Comment: #include <cliext/vector>

int main()
{
     return 0;
}

Вот весь файл, больше ничего нет.

Comment: Скорее всего не хватает какой-то из зависимых библиотек.

Comment: А проект у вас какого типа?

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, что имеется в виду под типом проекта. Если я правильно угадал, то Visual C++. CLR в настройках включен.

Comment: Да, именно, я хотел узнать, включена ли поддержка CLR.